# Using F2py in distutils

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I am using fortran programs within a python script, and trying to build and install it with a `setup.py` script, using `numpy.distutils`. However, I am not adept at knowing how to link in various code files, so I thought I'd ask the question here and hope someone could explain with clarity what to do with each type of file.

Let me explain a hypothetical situation, which happens to be fairly similar to my own. I have two files containing a module each that I wish to become `.so` files to be importable in python. Say they are `read.f90` (containg module `read` ) and `analyse.f90` (containing module `analyse` ) Both of these modules use subroutines that are defined in another file `subs.f90` which I am constantly adding to and updating. The module `analyse` also relies on another module `produce` in the file `produce.f90`, which I may tune up to begin with but basically i will let it be after this most likely. Furthermore, `analyse` also depends on an external library `libfoo.a`.

There are two layers to making this work - firstly, the `use` and `include` statements must be correct in the f90 files. Secondly, the Extension configuration in the `setup.py` file must be correct. So far, I know how to get the external library working - in the module `analyse`, put `use foo`, and in setup.py, in the Extension function, use the keywords

```
library_dirs = ["path/to/library"],
libraries = ["foo"],
include_dirs = ["path/to/directory/with/mod/files"]
```

However, for the rest I am unsure. I have some of it working but it doesn't seem to be the optimal way. Other parts aren't working at all. I just wondered if someone could explain clearly what to do?

Comment: Do you have all your .f90 files added to the list named "sources" in the Extension object? Apart from that it seems that you have everything you would need.

Comment: @DaveP - What do you mean by all the .f90 sources? Do you mean every .f90 file that has anything to do with the main modules? Ie. anything that is `use`d by `analyse` should JUST be in the sources list?

Comment: Because this (I think) means that f2py tries to make wrappers for every routine in all the modules. But I only want wrappers for the routines in `analyse`. Does this just mean I need to add all the .f90 sources to the depends list?

Comment: You need to add all the sources if you want them compiled into your .so file. If you want f2py to only wrap certain routines, then use its "only" command line option in the list called "f2py_options"

Comment: @DaveP - thankyou for your response. I will try adding them all and using the "only" command. However, should there be a way of pre-compiling modules that I don't actually care about importing to python, but which are needed by my `analyse` module, and then just linking them in?

Comment: @DaveP - it seems adding them all as sources and eliminating some routines via "skip" did not work. It compiles and installs fine, but when I import in Ipython, it comes up with an error "2) Symbol not found: __produce_MOD_subroutine_used". Have you any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like you are missing a library routine. Either you forgot to link something, or some necessary shared library is not in the path or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (on Linux). Also, you can test your module without installing it by passing the --inplace option to setup.py.